# Web proxy with WebSocket support, preferably in python

Tags: websocket, routes, reverse-proxy

Hello. I seek some guidance. I need a http web proxy with websocket support. The catch is, that I need to retrieve the context of HTTP request (headers, paramters, etc, used for retrieiving routing table) and in the same time I need websockets to work. So far I found onlt either HTTP-only proxies or TCP proxies that lack the context of HTTP request.
Is anyone aware of existence of a library or tool that will let me accomplish that?
I considered:

proxy.py, seems ugly and I couldn't make it work for my case in ~6 hours.

twisted, no experience nor success with this one either

nginx module in lua, looks promising and fast